# SOAP address picked wrong webservice for EJB as a WebService

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, jboss, wildfly

I am deploying JAVA EE application in WildFly 8.1.0 Final. After deployments its replaces address in SOAP address location to Remote Interface rather than to Stateless EJB WebService.

E.g,

```
@Remote

public interface SbbAccess {

...

}



@WebService(name="SbbAccess", serviceName="pfmjainslee11_diagram", targetNamespace="http://jee.v1.sbb.profile" )

@Addressing

@HandlerChain(file = "jaxws-handlers.xml")

@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)



public @Stateless class SbbAccessBean implements SbbAccess {

...

}
```

WSDL available from wildlfy is

```
 <wsdl:port binding="tns:pfmjainslee11_diagramSoapBinding" name="SbbAccessPort">

      <soap:address location="http://linus:8080/sbb---v1.EJB/pfmjainslee11_diagram/SbbAccess"/>

  </wsdl:port>
```

this should have been like

```
 <wsdl:port binding="tns:pfmjainslee11_diagramSoapBinding" name="SbbAccessPort">

      <soap:address location="http://linus:8080/sbb---v1.EJB/pfmjainslee11_diagram/SbbAccessBean"/>

  </wsdl:port>
```

Any suggestion what is causing this behavior?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour as a result of at least two of the following :

1. Your SLSB implements an `@Remote` interface
2. It's recommended by the specification that the interface name is mandatory in the JNDI lookup naming, when the SLSB implements a business interface.
3. The SLSB is being accessed remotely

The naming lookup options are:

```
 [/application name]/module name/enterprise bean name[/interface name]
```

In theory, you're not required to implement `@Remote`, so if it's causing you any discomfort, you could remove the interface implementation and you'll be fine